# Swift Standard Library w/ Extra Symbols

Tags: swift, swift3

A file with the following contents:

```
public class Foo {
  var x : Int = 0  
  var y : Unit?
}
```

when compiled as part of a 'MacOS Framework' succeeds (in Xcode 8 beta).  Notice that there is no `import` statement; I would expect the symbol `Unit` to be unbound - but apparently it is being found from the latest MacOS 'foundation'.

How do I ensure that the file is compiled w/o the `Unit` symbol?

Note: if I compile from the command line with `swift File.swift` then, in fact, `Unit` is unbound, as desired:

```
File.swift:12:11: error: use of undeclared type 'Unit'
  var y : Unit?
```

and, if I compile with the Swift Package Manager then Foundation is not implicitly imported.

So, how is Xcode inserting in implicit `import` that I don't need?

Comment: Same issue here. I created [SwiftFoundation][1] way before Swift was Open Sourced, and now I can't use it in Xcode 8.


  [1]: https://github.com/PureSwift/SwiftFoundation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building a framework, Xcode create a header file of `TheFramework.h` which includes contents like:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

//! Project version number for SBFrames.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double TheFrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for SBFrames.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char TheFrameworkVersionString[];
#endif
```

the inclusion of `Cocoa.h` imports `Foundation`.  To avoid including `Foundation` edit `TheFramework.h` to be empty.